# Java 8 Day Difference without the Time Component

Tags: java

My utility method accepts Java 7 Dates (I have no control over that since that is external) but needs to calculate a Day Difference. I am using the Java 8 ChronoUnit approach to be precise to avoid all the problems with leap years, daylight savings, etc.

```
public static long daysBetweenDatesWithSign(Date d1, Date d2) {
    Instant instant1 = d1.toInstant();
    Instant instant2 = d2.toInstant();
    long diff = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(instant1, instant2);
    return diff;
}
```

The result is not what I want because it takes time into account, e.g.

`( [Nov.5,2018 11:00am] , [Mar.5,2019 10:00am] )` gives `-119` rather than `-120`.

`( [Nov.5,2018 11:00am] , [Mar.5,2019 3:00pm] )` gives `-120`.

I need both of these to give `-120` because my function should be a Day/no-Time comparison.

But I don't want to go back to the Java 7 `Calendar`'s because of problems with leap years etc. To be precise I need the new Java 8 approach, but can I make it compare Days/no-Time in Java 8?

Comment: The day/no time requirement means different results in different time zones, so you need to choose a time zone for your operation. It is never the same date in all time zones.

Comment: Whatever problems java.util.Calendar might have, leap years are *not* one of them.  In fact, Calendar is fully capable of doing what you want, but whether you use Calendar or java.time, you will, as Ole V.V. points out, need to decide what timezone to use.  Nov. 5 2018 01:00 UTC and Nov. 5 2018 20:00 UTC are on the same calendar day in UTC, but not in US EST.

Comment: The time zone is US EST.

Comment: I can see that the first time span is indeed one day shorter than the second when you count hours and divide by 24 and cut off the fraction. So maybe, you should use class LocalDate instead if Instant.

Comment: I fixed my OP -- my test was with Nov. 5 2018, not Nov. 11 2018.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the value returned by that method for the given date values is `113` and `114`, respectively, not `-119` and `-120`.

Assuming you want the date difference according to your current (default) time zone, you can convert the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) values to [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) by calling [`atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) then [`toLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalDate--).

```
public static long daysBetweenDatesWithSign(Date d1, Date d2) {
    return daysBetweenDatesWithSign(d1, d2, ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
public static long daysBetweenDatesWithSign(Date d1, Date d2, ZoneId zone) {
    LocalDate instant1 = d1.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    LocalDate instant2 = d2.toInstant().atZone(zone).toLocalDate();
    return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(instant1, instant2);
}
```

*Test*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    test("Nov.11,2018 11:00am", "Mar.5,2019 10:00am");
    test("Nov.11,2018 11:00am", "Mar.5,2019 3:00pm");
}
public static void test(String d1, String d2) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM.d,yyyy hh:mma");
    System.out.println("[" + d1 + "] , [" + d2 + "] = " +
            daysBetweenDatesWithSign(fmt.parse(d1), fmt.parse(d2)));
}
```

*Output*

```
[Nov.11,2018 11:00am] , [Mar.5,2019 10:00am] = 114
[Nov.11,2018 11:00am] , [Mar.5,2019 3:00pm] = 114
```

Comment: So the `LocalDate` is the Java 8 trick to trim the time -- that's exactly what I wanted. Yes you're right about the typo I meant to write "Nov. 5" (not Nov. 11), I fixed my OP. thanks